# In Cucumber on Ruby w/rspec, how do I expect/assert a webmocked call in a Then clause?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, webmock

I'm writing a gem that acts as a client for a remote API, so I'm using webmock to mock out the remote API, testing with Cucumber with rspec-mock present too.

As part of my Cucumber tests I intend to stub my API in a `Given` clause but then I would like to specify that the remote API is called in a `Then` clause.

A really basic example would be:

**Feature file**

```
Scenario: Doing something that triggers a call
  Given I have mocked Google
  When I call my library
  Then it calls my Google stub
  And I get a response back from my library
```

**Step definition**

```
Given /I have mocked my API/ do
  stub_request(:get, 'www.google.com')
end

When /I call my library/ do
  MyLibrary.call_google_for_some_reason
end

Then /it calls my Google stub/ do
  # Somehow test it here
end
```

**The question:** 
How can I verify that my google stub has been called?

Side note: I'm aware I could use the `expect(a_request(...))` or `expect(WebMock).to ...` syntax but my feeling is I'll be repeating what's defined in my `Given` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer this myself, though it would be good for someone to verify this is correct and/or has no major pitfalls:

```
Given /I have mocked my API/ do
  @request = stub_request(:get, 'www.google.com')
end

Then /it calls my Google stub/ do
  expect(@request).to have_been_made.once
end
```

The bits to note are the assignment of `@request` and the expectation placed upon it in the `Then` clause.

In a limited test of two separate scenarios this approach seems to work.

Comment: I love webmock. Not enough to marry it. But it's quite satisfying.